# SharePoint online REST API - not showing all files

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I'm using the following REST endpoint for getting all items from a list:

> https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/sites/portal/myName/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('MyFolderTitle')/Items?$select=FileLeafRef,FileRef

I'm having weird problems with it. For example I have a subfolder with 2 pdf files, they have the same permissions, same everything, uploaded at the same time.
I can see them both when viewing them online and download them and everything, but with the REST call, I only get 1 file back.

What could be the reason for that behavior? Any help or hints would be appreciated because I'm losing my mind on this...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your endpoint it is return the data of folder and the files inside the folder.

To work with files and folder in document library you can refer below endpoints.

**to return all files and folder at a specific folder URL**

```
https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/sites/portal/myName/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(<folder url>)?$expand=Folders,Files
```

**To return only all files at a specific folder URL**

```
https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/sites/portal/myName/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(<folder url>)?$expand=Files
```

And if you want to work with endpoint mentioned in question

```
$.ajax({  
url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('LibraryName')/Items",  
type: 'GET',  
dataType: "json",  
headers: {  
    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
    "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose",  
    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()  
},  
success: function (data) {  
    for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {  
    //to check for not a folder
        if (data.d.results[i].FileSystemObjectType != 1) {            
        }  
    }  
},  
error: function (request, error) {  
    console.log(JSON.stringify(request));  
}  
});
```